# Parameter to take into account of a mosfet for a ZVS flyback driver

Tags: mosfet, zvs

What is there to see in a mosfet for a ZVS current or voltage? I have 4 mosfets APM4008N rated for 40V and 60A [Datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/mobile/824987/ANPEC/APM4008NU/1)

I want to use it for a homemade flyback from a flyback core.

Also, what type of capacitors are used for a ZVS and the size of the inductors and material can be used?

Taking advantage of this space, what should I also take into account for the winding of the flyback?